# Concatenate string and constant in resource file in C++ (MFC)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, resource-file

I have a C++ project with MFC and a resource file. In my About-Dialog I want to add a constant which contains the version of the programm.

```
IDD_ABOUTBOX DIALOG DISCARDABLE  34, 22, 237, 65
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About Monitor"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    ICON            IDR_MAINFRAME, IDC_STATIC, 11, 22, 20, 20
#ifdef __64BIT__
    LTEXT           "Communication Monitor V" APP_VERSION " x86_64", IDC_STATIC, 40, 13, 150, 8
#else
    LTEXT           "Communication Monitor V" APP_VERSION " x86_32", IDC_STATIC, 40, 13, 150, 8
#endif //__64BIT__
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK", IDOK, 200, 6, 32, 14
END
```

If it looks like this I get an error

```
1>src\monitor.rc(80): error RC2116: expecting number for ID
1>src\monitor.rc(80): error RC2108: expected numerical dialog constant
```

I also tried to concatenate it with a `+`

```
IDD_ABOUTBOX DIALOG DISCARDABLE  34, 22, 237, 65
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About Monitor"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    ICON            IDR_MAINFRAME, IDC_STATIC, 11, 22, 20, 20
#ifdef __64BIT__
    LTEXT           "Communication Monitor V" + APP_VERSION + " x86_64", IDC_STATIC, 40, 13, 150, 8
#else
    LTEXT           "Communication Monitor V" + APP_VERSION + " x86_32", IDC_STATIC, 40, 13, 150, 8
#endif //__64BIT__
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK", IDOK, 200, 6, 32, 14
END
```

but I get the error

```
1>src\monitor.rc(80): error RC2237: numeric value expected at 3.1.4.1
```

My next try was to call it like a function which I defined at the top of my `rc-file` but the error was like the both above.

Is it possible to concatenate a string and a variable in a rc-file within a LTEXT?

Comment: Please show the lines arround line 80 of monitor.rc.

Comment: Forget my previous comment. You cannot do this. Show the version dynamically. This requires 3-4 lines of code in the OnitiDialog function of your About dialog.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thx for your answer. I implemented it in my OnInitDialog function

Answer (score 3):

```
#define HSTR( N ) #N
#define STR( N ) HSTR( N )
#define VER_TXT( N ) Communication Monitor V##N x86_32
#define VER_STR( N ) STR( VER_TXT( N ) )
```

Works on VS2013. Should work on VS2010, too.

Comment: Symbols containing a double underscore, or symbols starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter (or symbols starting with an underscore at global scope) are reserved for use by the implementation.